# Azure WebJob running in WebApp without a JobSchedule/JobCollection - deploy with template

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-webjobs, azure-automation

Right. So this article: https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-create-web-jobs/ mentions that you can "You can run programs or scripts in WebJobs in your App Service web app in three ways: on demand, continuously, or on a schedule. There is no additional cost to use WebJobs."

Which is great, the free-alternative is a Scheduler Job Collection
with a job, but you're limited to running it every hour. So being able to run the webjob as part of the webapp, and on a higher frequency is what we need.

However, I'm really struggling to find any way of automating this process. Using the Azure portal to add a web job works fine - but the "automation script" generation tool doesn't generate a json file which includes anything about the webjob - so we'd always have to manually create it.

There are examples of custom templates for automating the creation of webjobs - but they all create said webjob as part of a Scheduler Job Collection, where we are limited to the hourly execution.

To summarise: I'm looking for a way of automating the creation of a webjob, linked to a web-app (such that it doesn't incur extra costs).

Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WebJobs are deployed by folder convention (as described [here](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Web-Jobs)), so deploying a WebJob is no different from deploying a Web App. It's simply a matter of getting the files in the right place.

Specifically, triggered WebJobs (manual or scheduled) go under `site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\triggered\{job name}` and continuous WebJobs go under `site\wwwroot\app_data\jobs\continuous\{job name}`.